# error message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to separate position information and movie title information that I pulled from an html document using BeautifulSoup.

I am pulling the information from lines like this:

```
<div class="filmo-row even" id="writer-tt1308667">
```

And I want to separate "writer" and "tt1308667" by "-"

My code is:

```
i=0
b = soup.find_all('div')
for row in b:
    Position_ttcode=row.get('id')
    print Position_ttcode
    split=Position_ttcode.split('-')
```

And I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

What am I missing? Please help!

Comment: Does the row actually have an ID?

Comment: Also, can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: Not sure how to show the full stack trace but print Position_ttcode gives something like this:actor-tt2133326
actor-tt0121955
None
None
None
None
None
more-episodes-tt0121955-actor
None
actor-tt1308667
actor-tt0372588
actor-tt0338479
actor-tt0263206
actor-tt0267939
actor-tt0158983
actor-tt0169299
actor-tt1626206
actor-tt0470926
actor-tt0205423
actor-tt0131857
actor-tt0124819

Comment: When you get the AttributeError, there should be a bunch of text telling you exactly where the error happened and what function calls were going on at that point. That's the stack trace.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/00/yl1lkzc90kg05rgs3m4g2qtr0000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/Parse_practice-417835156.088.py", line 48, in <module>
    split=Position_ttcode.split('-')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that not all of the `div` elements on the page have `id` attribute.

You should narrow down the search by providing either the class name or id atrribute to `find_all()`:

```
for div in soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'filmo-row'}):
    print div.get('id')
```

or, for example, you can check if `div` has an `id` attribute that *contains* `writer-` text by using `re` module:

```
for div in soup.find_all("div", {'id': re.compile('writer-'}):
    print div.get('id')
```

Hope that helps.